# Linkedin: List of requested permissions does not change when the application asks user for permissions

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am using linkedin login for one of my websites, however regardless of what "members permission" ([OAuth User Agreement](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer)) I set for my Linkedin application which used linkedin to login, when the user enters my application it only displays

The application like to acess some of your linkedin info:

1-YOUR PROFILE OVERVIEW

2-YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS

3- NETWORK UPDATES

I however want my application ask for

4- YOUR CONNECTIONS

as well!

But even if I select all the (member permissions [as show in image below]) it again only lists the three items above to the user! Any tips please?

[image: image below]

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention any language/library you're using. We use the ruby devise gem for LinkedIn Oauth which has a config setting for config.omniauth which is passed a scope, e.g.:

```
:scope => 'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo r_network'
```

The LinkedIn API documents the passing of scope with you auth request here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication